# ASPNET MVC authentication for multiple domains websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication

I have two websites:

1. The first one is an ASP.NET MVC website on .Net framework 4.7.2
2. The second one is an ASP.NET MVC Core Website on .Net Core 6

Important to note, these 2 websites are on **different domains**.

Actually, you can sign in on the first one by email, a Google account or a Facebook account.

I need to be able to sign in the second one (these 2 sites share the same client database).
Of course, if I am logged on the first one, I need to be logged on the second one, and vice versa.

I am looking for a free and "simple" solution.
I don't want to use ASP.NET Identity.

I suppose that I need a 3rd website which will manage the login/logout?
I found this interesting article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic but it's outdated : it uses asp.net webforms.

Any advice?

Comment: Do your websites share a database, or have some way of passing information between them (besides the client browser)?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, as I said, they share the same database

Comment: You can write your own Authentication and Authorization provider in ASP.Net. I'm not really sure what the limitations here are without knowing what you've attempted.

Comment: I use Net Identity and OAuth and persist with cookies.

Comment: @gunr2171 Authentication work with cookies. And a cookie is for one unique domain.
this is my main problem

Comment: Hi @, have your checked this official document about [share authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: @Rena Thanks for this, but this solution is for applications on different subdomains but not on different domains

Answer (score 0):

You can use Token Authorization from one application  User being logged in can click on a redirect button to another application
from clicking on link the first application will make a JWT token or any encrypted user values using Symmertic Algo. Then then route on Another (Second) Application
will Verify the JWT token or any encrypted user values to login In the User for Antoher Application and set the desired session in that application. you can also maintain the logs for logining in user in Database.